# Why the Range ExpandTo method edit the undo stack

Tags: ms-word, office-js

While working on a Word-Addin project, I use the method `expandTo` from the [Word.Range class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.range?view=word-js-preview#expandTo_range_) to expand two ranges together.

That method works as expected, it expands correctly two given ranges.

However, that method appears to have an unexpected side effect on the `undo` stack of Microsoft-Word Online (I haven't been able to test it on a native Microsoft-Word app).

Once the `expandTo` method called, the `undo` stack appears to have got the expanded selection as an item in the `undo` stack. So to actually `undo` something, I need to `ctrl + z` (or click on the `undo` button) multiple times.

Below is a simple trivial example, expanding the beginning of the document until the end. It does select the entire document as expected, but also add an item in the `undo` stack. From there, the `undo` functionality is not behaving as expected. Multiple `undo` is necessary to cancel the last text edit.

```js
Word.run(async (context): Promise<void> => {
      const firstParagraph = context.document.body.paragraphs.getFirst().getRange('Start')
      const lastParagraph = context.document.body.paragraphs.getLast().getRange('End')
      const expanded = firstParagraph.expandTo(lastParagraph).load('text')

      await context.sync()

      console.log(expanded.text) // Expanded selection text
})
```

This snippet doesn't trigger any error in the console.

Since the `expandTo` method doesn't actually change the active selection, why does it edit the `undo` stack?

Has anyone found a work-around for that issue? Is this an expected behaviour, or is there any way to avoid that side effect?

Thanks everyone.

Comment: This might be a bug. I recommend that you create an issue on the [office-js](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/new/choose) repo.